# Ignoring line breaks in Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Even if I use the m flag, javascript regex seems to isolate regex matching by lines.

Example:

```
"if\nend".match(/if(.*?)end/m)
=> null
```

I want this to match. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want `s` (a.k.a. "dotall"), not `m`, but javascript doesn't support that. A workaround:

```
"if\nend".match(/if([\s\S]*?)end/)
```